# How can you (partly) hide the design of your XPages application?

Tags: xpages

Can you (partly) hide the design of your XPages application when distributing them and how should you do so?

Comment: Sometimes when I deploy application there is problem with app configuration. Tweak of build properties, faces-config and so on is needed along with clean action. If you hide design, I think you will not be able to resolve such problems on site. Just to let you know...

Comment: I am not sure if you really can hide the design. If you are just hiding the db design you can still access the XPages source code with NotesPeek. Even deleting the source code in the *$FileData* items wouldn't help, because the compiled classes can still be decompiled...

Comment: I think no person ever will try to restore an application using notes peek. it will probably be faster to build it from scratch

Comment: @Thomas: you can copy the source code directly from a db with hidden design without any efforts. The java code is stored in the *$FileData* items as plain text. You can create an Agent to copy the docs to an "unprotected" db in about 5 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Patrick we hide the entire design for our IQJam and IdeaJam evaluations and all works fine. Not sure about how to hide only "portions" of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to partly hide specific objects, use these steps to hide the application design completly

1. Create a two new templates (ntf's) from your nsf application
2. do replace design using one of the templates to the other with the checkbox "hide forumlas and "lotusscript" ticked

Comment: Have you ever opened the application with notes peek? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did not test it for myself, but I would try to pack .class and .xml definitions of code generated for XPages (generally, content of WebContent\WEB-INF folder) into single JAR and deploy it to another database. This would work very well in case your code relies on views and forms in different database so you need not to bother with hiding regular Notes design elements.

There is still the option to decompile such classes what will reveal all bindings/scripts and component names, but at least you make it hard for someone.