# How to hide the entire design of Xpages like Replace design with option (Hide formulas and LotusScripts)?

Tags: java, javascript

I tested on hiding the entire design of Notes and XPages application with Replace Design (Hidden formula and script option). As a result, some XPages processes don't work.

If any tool, please suggest in details.

I did as you suggested in above blog post (Wissel,net). But I encountered same as the last comment of it (Stefan Zehnder). I tested by opening a XPage in which some custom controls as referred to a jar file (custom controls class in xsp package). As a result, I cannot see them in the xPage. Maybe the “composite-file” property in the xsp-config file (in WEB-INF) points to the wrong file or class. If you have any idea, please kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then I would suggest looking at the responses to a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234107/how-can-you-partly-hide-the-design-of-your-xpages-application)

Also, the following [blog post](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99W7MJ) by Stephan Wissel might give you some ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I will follow.

Comment: I did as you suggested in above blog post (Wissel,net). But I encountered same as the last comment of it (Stefan Zehnder). I tested by opening a XPage in which some custom controls as referred to a jar file (custom controls class in xsp package). As a result, I cannot see them in the xPage. Maybe the “composite-file” property in the xsp-config file (in WEB-INF) points to the wrong file or class. If you have any idea, please kindly help.